# gulp-uglify not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-uglify

Here is my repository
https://github.com/shellwe/QA_WP_Template

If you just needed to see the code snippet; here it is

```
gulp.task('uglify', function() {
      return gulp.src('js/all.min.js')
        .pipe(uglify())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('js/'));
});
```

I am running "gulp uglify" and I am getting the following errors.

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
 Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1534:18)
    at js_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:1542:11)
    at croak (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2089:9)
    at token_error (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2097:9)
    at unexpected (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2103:9)
    at semicolon (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2123:56)
    at simple_statement (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2314:73)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2183:19)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2136:24)
    at eval (eval at <anonymous> (C:\Users\sh3240\Documents\My Web Sites\wordpress\wp-content\themes\QA_WP_Template\node_modules\uglify-js\tools\node.js:28:1), <anonymous>:2904:23)
```

Most examples I see had concat and uglify in one process but since the concat part was working I broke them apart to show that. I know its something wrong with uglify, I just can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 4):

The error you are getting doesn't really explain much... However, according to the little "documentation" on **npm.js** of **gulp-uglify**,

> To help properly handle error conditions with Node stream, this project recommends the use of [**pump**](https://github.com/mafintosh/pump)

You can read up on [**gulp-uglify**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-uglify) and [**pump**](https://github.com/mafintosh/pump).

So, I tried the following:

```
# grab pump
npm install pump --save-dev
```

Then, in the **gulpfile.js**, I did the following:

```
gulp.task('uglify2', function (cb) {
    pump([
        gulp.src('./js/all.min.js'),
        uglify(),
        gulp.dest('./js/')
    ],
    cb
    );
});
```

The error that I am getting, which by the way, is a lot nicer than the error you are getting, is the following:

[image]

The problem seems to be on line [**191**](https://github.com/shellwe/QA_WP_Template/blob/master/js/all.min.js#L191), which suggests that there is something wrong with your **code**, rather than your **gulp task**.

Comment: Thanks for the notes, I saw on their site they used pump but in the examples I found it didn't have pump. I will try to fix the code first and then look into adding pump. I just downloaded the latest version of Bootstrap 4 and kept in the underscores js in there. I haven't made any of my own yet.
Thanks for your help though! I will have to look into resolving that error.

Comment: No problem! You don't necessarily have to use **pump** but as you can see it shows you exactly where the problem is... I've never worked with WordPress, so I don't really know what's going on in that JS file, however, I can see that it's using some of the newer syntax of JavaScript, which is why the **uglify** might not be liking it [?]; As a matter of fact, create yourself a simple script file that just displays some text in JavaScript, then uglify it by running your current task - I just did and it worked... Which suggests that there is something wrong with your **all.min.js** file

Comment: Thanks evvelss32, none of that JS pertains that much to wordpress, part of it is I have the bootstrap 4 alpha and I wonder if there is some code in there that is causing issues, more so I wonder if it is using ES2015 in the source files and we are supposed to convert that to standard js ourselves.

Comment: Yeah, I was curious myself if converting the JS file would help and I even tried using **gulp-babel** - https://babeljs.io/ - which is just another package for **gulp** - https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-babel - that converts the new JS syntax but I was still getting errors... You can check it out and try it yourself to see what errors it's giving you but it was basically the same line/statement that it didn't like... It could the bootstrap 4, especially considering it's still alpha...

Comment: @evvelss32 I am using pump for error tracing but i am getting ``Error: task completion callback called too many times`` this error. Can you please let me how can i fix this. Did you face this issue?